# the merciless lord of death

Tags: punctuation, commas, non-restrictive

a. The merciless lord of death in the underworld is waiting for me.

b. The merciless lord of death, in the underworld, is waiting for me.

c. The merciless lord of death who is in the underworld is waiting for me.

d. The merciless lord of death, who is in the underworld, is waiting for me.

Are the commas necessary to convey the idea that there is only one lord of death?

Would the comma-less sentences imply that there are other lords of death?

Many thanks

Comment: They all sound unnatural, though d is the least bad because it's a non-defining relative clause. A much better way of saying is "The merciless lord of death is waiting for me in the underworld".

Comment: Surely, if there is an 'underworld', containing at least one 'lord of death', then there is no such thing as death?

Comment: There could be a merciful lord of death.    There could be lords of death in other "worlds". The commas don't do diddly squat.